# Insert date in DD MM YY format in php myadmin

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to insert date in dd mm yy format and this is my php script

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

            $date = date('Y-m-d');

            $qry="INSERT INTO `nesbaty_offer`( `provider_id`, 
                                   `offer_punch`, 
                                   `offer_description`, 
                                   `terms`, 
                                   `sales_discount`, 
                                   `referal`, 
                                   `duration`, 
                                   `billing_type`, 
                                   `status`, 
                                   `service_location`, 
                                   `time`) VALUES('".$provider_id."',
                                   '".$offer_punch."',
                                   '".$offer_description."',
                                   '".$terms."',
                                   '".$sales_discount."',
                                   '".$referral."',
                                   '".$duration."',
                                   '".$billing_type."',
                                   '".$status."',
                                   '".$service_location."',
                                   '".$date."')";
```

Currently it is storing like this

```
YY-MM-DD
2018-05-22
```

But i want this

```
22-05-2018
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It's storing it like that because your date format is `$date = date('Y-m-d');` read the duplicate.

Comment: no, you can't use DD-MM-YY formate in MySQL. use PHP date function to manipulate this.

Comment: how do i convert it @hungrykoala

Comment: Read the link I provided. `$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

echo $newDate;`

Comment: but it;s a current date not manually?

Comment: That's just an example. you can opt out of the strtotime and just using your current code but change it to "d-m-Y"

Comment: Store dates using a date data type and a correct format for that data type

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the date format if you are using the `date` data-type in your database table.

But if you really want to change the format, I wold like to suggest using `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM tablename;
```